# Switching view controller in viewdidload method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults, viewcontroller

I am developing one iphone application in that i want to switch view controller by checking userdefaults. so i did the following:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if ([defaults objectForKey:@"keyString"] != nil) {
    nextViewController *redirectView = [[nextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nextViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.nextView = redirectView;
[self presentModalViewController:self.nextView animated:YES];
} else {
[defaults setObject:@"newValue" forKey:@"keyString"];
}
```

Its not working.. Is this the right way??? If not can anyone tell me how to do that..

Comment: are you using navigation controller or not?

Comment: Please provide more information in the question. What do you mean by "not working"? The if condition is not becoming true, or the condition is true but view is not showing?

Comment: @Aman No.. Am using View controller...

Comment: @taskinoor: Sorry.. Actually if condition working fine. but the view is not switching to next view...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont assign redirectView to self.nextView. Pass it directly like this

```
[self presentModalViewController:redirectView animated:YES];
```

Comment: what is nextView in your case actually ?  where you have it declared ?

Comment: netxView is an object which i created for nextViewController in interface (.h file)..

Comment: Then redirectView is also the same nextViewController's object.Why do u need to create two object of the same class ? Just try the answer i have posted now.

Comment: @iphoneFreak: I tried your solution but it doesnt help... Actually switching working properly in other actions but not in viewdidload action.. My doubt is can we switch view in viewdidload method???

Comment: Are you doing this operation when the application is about to be launched ? If so then do that in appDelegate's applicationDidFinishLaunching method.

Comment: Thank you so much.. It worked.. I put it in applicationDidFinishLaunching method and add sub view... Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 1):

Add the line

```
[self.view addSubview:nextView];
```

instead of

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.nextView animated:YES];
```

Comment: Its showing exception in console like following: [nextViewController superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: do you made the nextview as a property in .h ? what exception is this giving to you

Comment: Yes i have declared next view in .h file... Actually redirecting working fine when i used it in other actions (which occurs when button clicked) but its not working in viewdidload method...

Comment: Thank you so much.. Finally i got it working.. I put it in applicationDidFinishLaunching method and add sub view... Thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if ([defaults objectForKey:@"keyString"] != nil) 
{ nextViewController *redirectView = [[nextViewController alloc]init]; 
[self presentModalViewController:redirectView animated:YES]; 
redirectView=nil;
 } 
else { 
[defaults setObject:@"newValue" forKey:@"keyString"];
```

}